# Can we convert Android Apps to J2ME

Tags: android, java-me

I have already application designed for Android Phone (with source code). I wanted run this application on J2ME, Is there any direct conversion available or shall I need to start creating new Apps for J2ME ?

Comment: Do you want to create your Android app in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool available which can directly convert your Android application into Java ME application. You must need to manually create one Java ME application.

There are some reasons behind it. Few of are ..

1. In J2ME, Midlet interop (no "intents")
2. Impossible to implement alpha-blending, canvas transformation, etc.
3. 3rd party library integration which are only compatible with Android.

Possible things are,

1. Drawable to refer
2. Layout XML files rendering
3. Most of code logic
4. Web Service and Bean classes

Comment: JavaME is limited compared to Android, in many aspects. And the code logic is also somewhat different. (Which one you prefer probably depends on which platform you started out with). Alpha-blending IS possible with JavaME though.

Comment: @mr_lou yes 100% agree with you.